# Where does Adobe AIR look for the proxy settings in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: proxy, networking, air

I am building an AIR app that makes a call to a remote server within the company network

The Adobe AIr runtime seems to be looking at the proxy settings of the OS.I have added the location to the No_proxy variable in bashrc under my user id.

whenever i call `adl` to run the code it seems to be accessing the proxy server , causing time out problems and  `Actionscript  ioError 2032`

Where are the proxy settings in Ubuntu Ibex that Adobe AIR runtime seems to be accessing and can we add a `no_proxy` to that to avoid hitting the proxy server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Ashutosh Sharma](http://blogs.adobe.com/ashutosh/2008/07/air_and_proxies_on_linux.html):

> We've decided to use the current desktop environment's proxy settings, with the option of having these overridden with an environment variable.
>
> On KDE, proxy settings can be set using kcontrol (KDE Control Center). On GNOME, these can be set using gnome-network-preferences (or directly using gconf-editor).

I've just discovered that, as so often, the proxies have to be set manually, not using a .pac file.